# How to use a 2d texture array in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, stb-image

I am trying to load textures into a 2d array and than apply them.

But the screen only shows Black.

This is my code.

Creating Textures.

```
void int loadTexture(char const* path)
{
    glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, &textureID);
   
    int width, height, nrComponents;
    unsigned char* data1 = stbi_load("C:\\Temp\\RED.png" , &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);   // Load the first Image of size 512   X   512  (RGB)
    unsigned char* data2 = stbi_load("C:\\Temp\\BLUE.png", &width, &height, &nrComponents, 0);  // Load the second  Image of size 512   X   512   (RGB)
    glTextureStorage3D(textureID, 1, GL_RGB8, width, height, 2);
   
     GLenum format;
     format = GL_RGB;

     glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data1);
     glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 1 , 0, 0, 2, width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);

      glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
      glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
      glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
      glTextureParameteri(textureID, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
                
      stbi_image_free(data1);
      stbi_image_free(data2);
 
      glBindTextureUnit(0, textureID);
}
```

Using the textures.

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClearColor(0.1f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

         Shader.use();
        Shader.setFloat("textureUnit", 1);   // Bind the first texture unit of the texture array
        glBindTextureUnit(0, textureID);  
        renderQuad();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
```

Vertex Shader.

```
#version 460 core

layout( location = 0)in vec2 aPos;
layout( location = 1 )in vec2 a_uv;
out vec2 f_uv;

void main() {
f_uv = a_uv;
gl_Position =   vec4(aPos ,0.0, 1.0 );
};
```

Fragment Shader.

#version 460 core

```
uniform sampler2DArray u_tex;
in vec2 f_uv;
out vec4 FragColor;
uniform float textureUnit;


in vec2 TexCoord2;
void main() {

        vec3 texCoordTest = vec3( f_uv.x , f_uv.y , textureUnit);
        vec4 color = texture(u_tex  , texCoordTest);            
        FragColor = color ; 
                                
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5th argument of [`glTextureSubImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml) is the *zoffset*. This is 0 for the 1st texture and 1 for the 2nd texture. The 2nd argument is the *level* not the number of levels:

<s>`glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data1);`</s>
<s>`glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 1 , 0, 0, 2, width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);`</s>

```cpp
glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data1);
glTextureSubImage3D(textureID, 0, 0, 0, 1, width, height, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data2);
```

Comment: Thank you again very much , Just one more question if i need to create mipmaps levels do i need to call  glGenerateTextureMipmap(textureID);

Comment: @Summit Yes, but you need to create a storage  with the correct number of levels. e.g.: `mipmapLevels = (GLsizei)floor(log2(std::max(width, height)))`. Load the images to level 0 and call `glGenerateTextureMipmap`. See http://www.xphere.me/2020/06/mipmapping-effects-of-not-having-it-and-how-to-setup-in-opengl-4-5/